# How to divide a pandas dataframe into several dataframes by month and year

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe with different columns (like price, id, product and date) and I need to divide this dataframe into several dataframes based on the current date of the system (current_date = np.datetime64(date.today())).

For example, if today is 2020-02-07 I want to divide my main dataframe into three different ones where df1 would be the data of the last month (data of 2020-01-07 to 2020-02-07), df2 would be the data of the last three months (excluding the month already in df1 so it would be more accurate to say from 2019-10-07 to 2020-01-07) and df3 would be the data left on the original dataframe.

Is there some easy way to do this? Also, I've been trying to use Grouper but I keep getting this error over an over again: NameError: name 'Grouper' is not defined (my Pandas version is 0.24.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) for last 1mont and 3month datetimes, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2019-10-10', periods=20, freq='5d')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'id': range(20)})  
print (df)
         date  id
0  2019-10-10   0
1  2019-10-15   1
2  2019-10-20   2
3  2019-10-25   3
4  2019-10-30   4
5  2019-11-04   5
6  2019-11-09   6
7  2019-11-14   7
8  2019-11-19   8
9  2019-11-24   9
10 2019-11-29  10
11 2019-12-04  11
12 2019-12-09  12
13 2019-12-14  13
14 2019-12-19  14
15 2019-12-24  15
16 2019-12-29  16
17 2020-01-03  17
18 2020-01-08  18
19 2020-01-13  19
```

---

```
current_date = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d')
print (current_date)
2020-02-07 00:00:00

last1m = current_date - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
last3m = current_date - pd.DateOffset(months=3)

m1 = (df['date'] > last1m) & (df['date'] <= current_date)
m2 = (df['date'] > last3m) & (df['date'] <= last1m)
#filter non match m1 or m2 masks
m3 = ~(m1 | m2)

df1 = df[m1]
df2 = df[m2]
df3 = df[m3]
```

---

```
print (df1)
         date  id
18 2020-01-08  18
19 2020-01-13  19

print (df2)
         date  id
6  2019-11-09   6
7  2019-11-14   7
8  2019-11-19   8
9  2019-11-24   9
10 2019-11-29  10
11 2019-12-04  11
12 2019-12-09  12
13 2019-12-14  13
14 2019-12-19  14
15 2019-12-24  15
16 2019-12-29  16
17 2020-01-03  17

print (df3)
        date  id
0 2019-10-10   0
1 2019-10-15   1
2 2019-10-20   2
3 2019-10-25   3
4 2019-10-30   4
5 2019-11-04   5
```

Comment: @SarahKerrigan - I change [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)  - `m1 = df['date'].between(last1m, current_date)` to `m1 = (df['date'] > last1m) & (df['date'] <= current_date)`, reason is between is less general like this solution. It mean `between` is like `m1 = (df['date'] >= last1m) & (df['date'] <= current_date)` or with inclusive=False `m1 = (df['date'] > last1m) & (df['date'] < current_date)`, if need one interval open and one close not possible.